# Who mines in a consortium network?

Tags: mining

So if I want to setup a consortium network between two companies who would do the mining? The companies want to use the consortium network to purchase goods using ether.

I’d like some clarity in the following.

I’ve read that two miners each is a good rule of thumb having 50% of the miners each for validating the chain. Is this correct?

What is to stop someone starting up another miner?

We don’t want miners to get rewards as this should just be to validate the chain and we primarily want the ether sent from one account to another to allow purchases?

What happens if more companies get on board, would they need to setup miners to validate the chain on there side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a regular network, you cannot stop anybody from mining and thereby possibly manipulating data. 
In your case, you would need a [permissioned](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) network. In this case, only nodes with permissioned addresses can mine transactions. 
Even more suitable would be using a [Quorum](https://www.google.de/search?q=ethereum%20quorum&oq=ethereum%20quorum&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l3.3678j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) network, as this would even allow privacy among the participating parties and eliminate the (in a PoA network not so relevant, but annoying) transaction fees for your consortium members.

Comment: I'll need to look into the Quorum network more before I can accept your answer. From what I've read it sounds like authors are saying everything it does can be mimicked by a centralised database. I also feel that someone would have ownership of this ledger if they are the one regulating the permissions?

Comment: No, a centralized DB would have all data, if not end-to-end encrypted. The latter is the case with Quorum, as nodes there have a private state trie, too, and the private transactions are done P2P only. On the main ledger only hashes of the tx are stored, so the correctness of all private transactions can be verified afterwards in the case of a dispute.